# PHP know when service completes converting

Tags: php, symfony, while-loop

I am using video converting service in my Symfony app. My problem is I need to know when video converting is completed. The flow is: I trigger video convert service and when video was successfully converted video service updates video status to 'converted'. If failed then status is 'failed'. I need to keep checking video status before setting video to post.

```
   public function setVideo(Post $post, Video $video){

    if($video->getStatus() != 'ready_for_conversion'){
        throw new ApiException('video cannot be processed');
    }else{
        $videoService = $this->container->get('app.video_service');
        $videoService->submitJob($video);
        $converting = true;
        while ($converting) {
            $status = $video->getStatus();
            if($status == Video::STATUS_CONVERTED) {
                break;
            }elseif ($status == Video::STATUS_FAILED){
                throw new ApiException('video failed');
            }
        }

        $post->setVideo($video);
    }
}
```

When I run this code I get

`php.CRITICAL: Fatal Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded`

Even though video service updated status successfully after some time.

Comment: Seems your video converting more than 30 seconds. Try `set_time_limit(600);` if it suitable for you

Comment: This is a good example to make use of custom events. You can dispatch an event once the converting is done and update your entity in an event listener. Can you post the source of your converter or at least parts of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about the architecture of your application your question is difficult to answer. I'm going to assume that the videos your uploading are going to take a bit of time to finish processing. Seems like a safe bet, because video is notoriously computationally expensive. And that is what's breaking your code (as you can see from that error). Basically it takes longer than 30 seconds to process a video, which is not surprising.

To fix this you need to rethink your solution. Best way to do that is to go back to thinking about your goal. If the `Post` object in your code is an article or blog post of some type and you're trying to prevent a video from being displayed or used before it's actually ready then I'd suggest you let the post associate the video and move the checking logic into the model. You could do the following in that case:

```
class Post
{
    ...
    public function isVideoAvailable()
    {
        return isset($this->video) && Video::STATUS_CONVERTED === $this->getVideo()->getStatus();
    }
}
```

Then wrap that into you're view template when displaying or in api responses. Here's a twig example:

```
{% if post.isVideoAvailable() %}
<div class="video">
    <!-- put video embed code here -->
</div>
{% endif %}
```

If you have good reasons to prevent the video from being associated to the `Post`. Then you'll probably need to break this into several controller actions. One to accept the video and start the processing, another to poll against to see when it's completed, and the last one to associate the video (you can combine the last two, just seems messy to me as it's not SRP, but you may have a good reason for that too).

There are other options too like using web sockets or http streaming, but that gets complicated to explain here.

The short answer is, it's bad to use any web service endpoint for long running processes. Doing that has a bunch of other performance problems that will surface at some point, so don't do that.